# encodeRestorableState for unsaved documents

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

The documentation for NSDocument states:

> Subclasses can override this method and use it to restore any
>   information that would be needed to restore the document’s window to
>   its current state. For example, you could use this method to record
>   references to the data currently managed by the document and displayed
>   by the window. (Do not store the actual data itself. Store only
>   references to the data so that you can load it later from disk.) You
>   must store enough data to reconfigure the document and its window to
>   their current state during a subsequent launch of the app.

What does "Do not store the actual data itself." actually mean?  Is this a hard and fast rule?  Or is it more of a guideline?

In particular, I'm wondering about the case of documents with unsaved changes in them.  Is it "permissible" to store the unsaved changes (which may be everything if this is a new document)?  Or, do I need to save the data off in a file somewhere... and if so, where is the preferred location?

I don't want to restore a bunch of identical (blank) documents if I had multiple unsaved new documents when the application was shut down.

Thanks for any hints on the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  It hit me in the shower this morning (where I make most of my tech breakthroughs).

I am pretty sure now that the key is to get autosaving working with my application.